# MS SQL rollup percentage column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using rollup to sum a table containing fields `company`, `sales`, `cost` and `margin`. This gives me the summarized columns, but I need to show a summarized percentage of the margin as a percentage of sales for each company summary.

This is my current statement:

```
SELECT coalesce(CAST(Company AS VARCHAR(30)), 'Grand Total:') AS Company,
       SUM(Sales)                                             AS 'TOTSALES',
       SUM(CostVal)                                           AS 'TOTCOST',
       SUM(MarginVal)                                         AS 'TOTMAR'
FROM   DailySalesSum
GROUP  BY Company WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: `100.0 * SUM(MarginVal) /  SUM(Sales)` or you need something different?

Comment: That's what I need, where would that go in the staement

Comment: Just add it in to the select list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT coalesce(CAST(Company AS VARCHAR(30)), 'Grand Total:') AS Company,
       SUM(Sales)                                             AS 'TOTSALES',
       SUM(CostVal)                                           AS 'TOTCOST',
       SUM(MarginVal)                                         AS 'TOTMAR',
       100.0 * SUM(MarginVal) / SUM(Sales)                    AS 'MARGINPERCENT'
FROM   DailySalesSum
GROUP  BY Company WITH ROLLUP;
```

Do as Martin says and add it as an extra field to your statement as shown above.